# Return bit value from SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, byte, bit

The best way to explain this is with code:

```
byte roominspiration = 0;
query = "SELECT room_inspiration FROM Room WHERE room_id = @room_id); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
using (sqlConnection1)
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection1))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@room_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@room_id"].Value = roomid;
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null)
    {
      roominspiration = (byte)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is update the value of 'roominspiration' to whatever the value of that record in the database is.  The field in the database is a bit datatype with a default value of 0.  It is always set correctly, so this shouldn't an issue in it returning null.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way to do what I'm doing.  My C# skills aren't too good, but I'm trying to learn!

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use the `bool` .NET data type here.

So,

```
bool roominspiration = false;
query = "SELECT room_inspiration FROM Room WHERE room_id = @room_id); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
using (sqlConnection1)
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection1))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@room_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@room_id"].Value = roomid;
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    roominspiration = ((bool?)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).GetValueOrDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this line is erroring: roominspiration = ((bool?)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).GetValueOrDefault();

It runs okay if I comment the line out but errors if not commented.

Comment: Actually, my bad completely - there's a syntax error in the query!  Thanks for your help with this - the bool way works nicely now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Also, note you can use `Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of `Parameters.Add`—a little bit cleaner code that way.

Answer (score 1):

What you could also do to convert the bit to a bool is 
keep the roominspiration defined as a byte and at the end 
convert it like

```
roominspiration = ConvertToBoolean(the value you are wanting to convert);
```